# Not able to capture the hyperlink values from webtable" http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies"

Tags: hyperlink, automationanywhere

Not able to capture the hyperlink values from webtable. 
Trying to capture the  table (1) in the following link. " **"http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies"**.
 Table extracted without one column values.

During web recorder the preview contains the values, when it was extracted values are not available.

Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in advanced settings when extracting a table to extract tags, you have to save to a file. I have found this to work to get URL’s